# How to show a presentAlert inside a method then on Ionic 4?

Tags: firebase, alert, ionic4

I'm trying to show a presentAlert inside a "then method", adding a document on a collection (Firebase + Ionic 4, if its successful, it should appear the alert). But the problem is I cannot reach the presentAlert method if i'm calling from inside the then method.

```
  addObject() {
this.afs.collection("Objects").add(this.object)
  .then(function () {
    console.log("Object successfully written!");
    this.presentAlert() //Doesn't work
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }); 
 }

  async presentAlert() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Thank you!',
      message: 'This Object has been uploaded succesfully :)',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
```

Comment: Why are u using async before `function()`?

Comment: Was trying, i know it doesnt work, im not using it anymore

Comment: Ohh yes u can't reach it, use arrow functions instead, because here it's in another context when u use `function()`

Comment: I dont understand it sorry, can you explain the solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following:

```
  .then(function () {
    console.log("Object successfully written!");
    this.presentAlert() //Doesn't work
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }); 
 }
```

into this:

```
.then(() => {
    console.log("Object successfully written!");
    this.presentAlert() //Doesn't work
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  }); 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks so kind, I know that's stupid but it was getting me off for a while... jaja